# Is there a way to recreate the original openapi/swagger specs from code auto-generated using swagger-codegen?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I have the generated client code but unfortunately not the original specs. Is there a way for me to reverse generate the specs from the codebase?

Answer (score 0):

If the auto-generated code doesn't contain the specs (YAML/JSON), I think the best you can do it to contact the REST API owners to see if they have a copy of the original specs.